# Way to externalize underscore templates

Tags: underscore.js, marionette

I'm starting with marionette.js and was searching for ways to use external templates instead of script ones. I have read Derick's post about how it is [a bad idea to load templates in async way](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/09/asynchronously-load-html-templates-for-backbone-views/). I have also checked BBCloneMail to see how templates are loaded there. It turned out that those are included into the index.html page when the web application loads. I wonder if this is a good idea for some big applications that might have 30+ templates and 10+ screens (sub-applications). Am I mistaken?

I was thinking that, instead of loading all templates at once I would load them when I load some specific sub-application. Is it a good way or is there a better way of dealing with external underscore templates?

If it may help in providing the answer, I've planned to use module system provided by marionette, not RequireJS.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.  I found an example online, I modified it to make it work for what I was doing it for (they were pulling html files and I wanted to pull ASP.net pages) but I can't find the example online again to give that person the credit.  However, here is my modified code.

The first is the template loader:

```
if (!window.JackTemplateLoader) {

function JackTemplateLoader(params) {
    if (typeof params === 'undefined') params = {};
    var TEMPLATE_DIR = params.dir || '';

    var file_cache = {};

    function get_filename(name) {
        if (name.indexOf('-') > -1) name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf('-'));
        return TEMPLATE_DIR + name;
    }

    this.get_template = function (name) {
        var template;
        var file = get_filename(name);
        var file_content;
        var result;
        if (!(file_content = file_cache[name])) {
            $.ajax({
                url: file,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    file_content = data; 
                    file_cache[name] = file_content;
                }
            });
        }
        return file_content;
    }

    this.clear_cache = function () {
        template_cache = {};
    };

  }
 }
```

Then inside my Marionette App, I created an addInitilizer that over writes Marionettes template loader.

```
    app.addInitializer(function (options) {
    app.JackTemplateLoader = new JackTemplateLoader({ dir: "/api/ApplicationScreens/", ext: '' });
    Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.loadTemplate = function (name) {
        if (name == undefined) {
            return "";
        } else {
            var template = app.JackTemplateLoader.get_template(name);
            return template;
        }
    };
```

The best part is the template loader will cache my templates so they are only loaded once.  I am working on making a change to this code to send a flag that will indicate whether or not I want to cache the template.

Comment: Thank you, looks very promising :) Also found the [following article](http://johndavidmathis.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/preloading-backbone-marionette-templates-2/).

Answer (score 1):

@Roman

We load templates from external files using requireJS!text.  That is how we make templates modularized.

You can take a look at the [example in here](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not using RequireJS in my application.

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm late, but i have solved the topic by using JST Templates. A gulp process creates the JST object on runtime. I override marionette templates:

```
// use jst templates by overriding marionette render
Marionette.Renderer.render = function(template, data) {
    // allow No template
    if (template === undefined) {
        return '';
    }
    if (!window.JST[template]) {
        throw 'Template "' + template + '" not found!';
    }
    // underscore create a template
    return _.template(JST[template](data));
};
```

Check this usage on my skeleton example for this:
https://github.com/LucaMele/skeleton-marionette-require-gulp

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 10+ subapps with 30+ templates, assuming 3 templates per subapplication average, it would be a really bad idea to load them by 3, unless the templates itself are very heavy. Also, today internet is quite fast everywhere I would not afraid creating a bit more heavier pages.

However, having 30+ templates in a single html file makes mess. In this case I would recommend using [Jammit](https://github.com/documentcloud/jammit) or something similar. It lets you have separate html file for every template in development and builds it into a single file for production.

Comment: Numbers were only an example, but the application itself is pretty big. Thank you for your answer though, I will check Jammit. But I think I might end up with loading templates in async way.